# How to stop overriding a version of transitive dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven

**TL;DR**

I've got a dependency management issue. I would like to simplify description of my problem, so I am not going to post full stack trace of NoClassDefFoundError:.. VeryImportantStuff and etc.

Briefly speaking, I use 2 dependencies: *A-1.1* and *B-1.0* for my project *C*. I cannot take another version of either *A* or *B*. The *B-1.0* depends on *A-1.0*. An author of *A* doesn’t respect the backward compatibility rules and latest version (1.1) of the A library simply doesn’t have the class `VeryImportantStuff.class`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thirdparty.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version> <!-- overrides B->A version !!! ((( -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.another.thirdparty.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <!--
    <dependencyManagement> 
       <dearMavenIbegYouPleaseUseThisDependency>

           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.thirdparty.lib</groupId>
              <artifactId>A</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>  PLEASE!!!
           </dependency>

       </dearMavenIbegYouPleaseUseThisDependency>
    </dependencyManagement> 
    -->
</dependency>
```

**The Question**

How to tell the *B* (or what can I add to my pom.xml) that it should use version 1.0 of A, not the 1.1 which is specified in the pom.xml taking into account that my application code should use *A-1.1*?

Comment: if *...B-1.0 depends on A-1.0* then B-1.0 is build using A's 1.0 only and in order to insure that your project doesn't get 1.0 just use `<exclusions>` in B's dependency

Comment: When B-1.0 runs it cannot find the required A-1.0's classes in runtime. There are A-1.1 classes in runtime.

Comment: What do you mean *When B-1.0 runs*? When you declare it(B) as a dependency, assume it is already build using the dependencies mentioned in its own pom.xml

Comment: The B-1.0 is already built using its own dependencies. My local repository contains `b-1.0.jar`. But this jar doesn't contain its dependencies. There are separate jars: `a-1.0.jar` and `a-1.1.jar`. So when I run my application the Java ClassLoader throws NoClassDefFaundError coz he cannot find `a-1.0.jar`'s classes. It seems my classpath is dirty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an exclusion to dependency `B` and tell that you don't need `A`. Then add `A` with version 1.1 as your dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.another.thirdparty.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.thirdparty.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>        
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No success. In runtime B still use 1.1 of A

Comment: So, do you want both version 1.0 and 1.1 of `A` in a single JVM. If yes then it's not possible. If you need two versions of same class at runtime, only thing you have is osgi.